What can Windows change in a file after downloading it to end up with a different md5 hash?
I've downloaded the entire content of my Google Drive using PyDrive2 package for Python, and did a comparison of the files from my local drive and the content on my Google Drive and a few of the files have different md5 hashes. None of the files on my local drive have been touch, but . . .
From my local drive . . .
    "Pay Stubs/Wendy's/01-11-2022.pdf": {
        "size": 3872,
        "checksum": "1891f224f046ef7ff05b9dc69e275155"
    },

From Google Drive . . .
    "Pay Stubs/Wendy's/01-11-2022.pdf": {
        "size": 3872,
        "checksum": "60e94f02230b42d5288878550f01f315"
    },


I've downloaded byte content of the file with fsspec and generated a md5 hash locally and the hash is what it should be.
            # GoogleDrive inherits pydrive2.fs.GDriveFileSystem https://docs.iterative.ai/PyDrive2/fsspec/
            # pydrive2.fs.GDriveFileSystem inherits fsspec.AbstractFileSystem
            # https://filesystem-spec.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#fsspec.spec.AbstractFileSystem
            Drive = GoogleDrive()
            print(Drive.info(path = 'root/Pay Stubs/Wendy\'s/01-11-2022.pdf'))

            with Drive.open(path = 'root/Pay Stubs/Wendy\'s/01-11-2022.pdf', mode = 'rb') as rfile:
                print(hashlib.md5(string = rfile.read(), usedforsecurity = True).hexdigest())

{'name': "root/Pay Stubs/Wendy's/01-11-2022.pdf", 'type': 'file', 'size': 3872, 'checksum': '60e94f02230b42d5288878550f01f315'}
60e94f02230b42d5288878550f01f315

Anyway, my question is, what could Windows possibly change in the byte content of the file to end up with a different MD5 hash after downloading the file?

Anything could have been changed, because in cryptography, even small changes in a phrase can lead to very different hashes, like how "Pass" and "pass" produce very unique results.

If I wanted to know exactly which bytes are different, I'd create a hex-dump (preferably containing both representations, hex codes and ASCII-Characters) for both files and compare those with a diff tool like meld.
If I had to guess, I'd say you'll find the difference in some sort of timestamp.

So PyDrive2's innocence has been proven?

Yes, it isn't with pydrive2. The local MD5 hash is being done after I've downloaded the file.

I figured out the source of my problem. It isn't with windows or pydrive2. It was in a function I wrote to generate the checksum in a try except and with chardet.detect(rfile.read(1024)['encoding'] returned ascii instead of None so the pdf file was being read as a text file and not a a binary file.

This would be difficult to pinpoint a root cause but there a few possibilities that come to mind:

Alternative Data Streams (ADS): Windows can allow files to have additional streams of data associated with them, like keeping track of where the file may have come from. This is usually something that the user cannot see when you download a file.

Antivirus Software: During file scanning, your antivirus could make modifications to the file.


(Both the first and second cases are symptoms of metadata sneaking its way into the file)

File Corruption: Perhaps a less likely case is that the file is corrupted when you download the file and either the file or your storage device is corrupted somewhere.


Truthfully, if you're very curious about the devices, you could technically do a byte-to-byte comparison between the two files but I'm not really sure how you can do that with Google Drive.

With pydrive2.fs (fsspec) I can "open" and download the bytes form the file, instead of the file itself.

Alternative data streams don’t have anything to do with the raw file data, which is what’s being hashed. I can almost guarantee one got added (Most things on Windows flag ‘remote’ files with their point of origin in the Zone.Identifier ADS), but that is completely invisible to anything reading the file contents (just like with xattrs on Linux/BSD/BeOS/Solaris/AIX or named forks on macOS), so it should have zero impact on the hash.

@phpjunkie the bytes ARE the file itself.

@alkanen Right, I was talking about downloading the byte content of the file and not the file itself. When you click on a file to download your downloading the file, and to use md5 to hash a file you have to open it and hash the byte content of the file, if it is a binary file. With a text file you have to encode the string content in the file and then you can use md5 to hash the contents of the file.

@phpjunkie That's not how text files work... It's kind of the opposite. The contents of all files are the same kind of 'binary' – i.e. the string contents are encoded when writing to file and (optionally) decoded when loading, not the other way around.

@grawity_u1686, You right. I was thinking python when I said that. In Python when you open a text file it returns the string content that has to be re-encoded back to binary.

That doesn't happen because it is a text file – it happens because you open it in text mode, which asks python to decode the original binary contents upon reading. If you don't want that, open it in binary mode.

And to do what @grawity_u1686 is talking about, you do open(filename, "rb") and any read() command on the file object will return a byte array to you.
